# Defining theorem environment inside a shaded box

Tags: environments, texstudio

How do I define `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` inside the shaded box `\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{lightgray}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}`

I know I can just call the `resheading` command every time I write a theorem, but it'd be more convenient if that process itself were automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly if this is what you want, but you can try the following:

Define a new theorem to get the counter

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
```

Redefine the environment to use the shaded block

```
\renewenvironment{thm}{
\stepcounter{thm}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}
\begin{shaded}
{\bfseries Theorem \thethm: }\\
}
{
\end{shaded}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}
```

Then use the newly-created environemnt

```
\begin{thm}
 This is my theorem
\end{thm}
```

[image]

Comment: this was just top of the mind for a simple use, but you can always increment it